# Is there a way to render a BasicDBObject into Map<String,String> with MongoDB/Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

Is there a way to render a `BasicDBObject` into `Map<String,String>` with MongoDB/Java?

```
public Map<String,String> getObjectByKeyValue(String dbname, String collname, String key, String value) {

    Map<String,String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();

    DB db = mongo.getDB(dbname);
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection(collname);

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put(key, value);
    DBCursor cur = coll.find(query);
    while (cur.hasNext()){
        DBObject obj = (DBObject) cur.next(); // Correct, or use BasicDBObject?
        // How to get each pair stored in the object be pushed into a Map<String,String> ?
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call `toMap()` function on BasicBSONObject which returns `LinkedHashMap<String,Object>`