# Java, java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.bson.BSONObject

Tags: java, mongodb

I have been working wrote a MapReduce Program to implement word count with data store in MongoDB. I want to cast BSONObject to HashMap in Java, but it return the error

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.bson.BSONObject
```

And my code

```
BasicBSONObject result = new BasicBSONObject();
HashMap<String, Integer> mymap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
[snippt]
for (BSONWritable val : values) {
{
    HashMap<String, Integer> temp = (HashMap<String, Integer>) val.getDoc().toMap();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry :  temp.entrySet()) {
        if (mymap.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            mymap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()+1);
        }
        else {
            mymap.put(entry.getKey(), 1);
        }
    }

}
result.putAll((BSONObject)mymap);
```

I want to my `ｍymap` into `result`. Since `mymap` is a `HashMap` instance, I think `putAll` method is a choice.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `toMap` returns a `Map` not a `HashMap`.

Comment: Can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477923/is-there-a-way-to-render-a-basicdbobject-into-mapstring-string-with-mongodb-ja/8478668

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not need to be cast

see https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.10/apidocs/bson/org/bson/BsonDocument.html#putAll(java.util.Map)

Comment: api page you linked require authentication now :)